# Could not get apiVersions from Kubernetes: Unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, kubectl, azure-aks

While trying to deploy an application got an error as below:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: could not get apiVersions from Kubernetes: unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs: metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

Output of **`kubectl api-resources`** consists some resources along with the same error in the end.

**Environment**: Azure Cloud, AKS Service

Comment: Could you post the output of `kubectl get pod -A` and describe your environment in more details- cloud/on-prem cluster/ minikube, OS etc. ?

Comment: @KFC_ Got the solution

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solution:

The steps I followed are:

1. `kubectl get apiservices` : If metric-server service is down with the error **CrashLoopBackOff** try to follow the step 2 otherwise just try to restart the metric-server service using **kubectl delete apiservice/"service_name"**. For me it was **v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io** .
2. `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` and found out that pods like metrics-server, kubernetes-dashboard are down because of the main coreDNS pod was down.

---

For me it was:

```
NAME                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/coredns-85577b65b-zj2x2   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          13m
```

3. Use `kubectl describe pod/"pod_name"` to check the error in coreDNS pod and if it is down because of **/etc/coredns/Corefile:10 - Error during parsing: Unknown directive proxy**, then we need to use **forward** instead of **proxy** in the yaml file where coreDNS config is there. Because CoreDNS version 1.5x used by the image does not support the **proxy** keyword anymore.

Comment: Thanks!!!

this not only solved my issue with the error but also solved issue with namespace were not getting deleted

after using this its fixed now :)

Answer (score 3):

This error happens commonly when your metrics server pod is not reachable by the master node. Possible reasons are

1. metric-server pod is not running. This is the first thing you should check. Then look at the logs of the metric-server pod to check if it has some permission issues trying to get metrics
2. Try to confirm communication between master and slave nodes.
3. Try running `kubectl top nodes` and `kubectl top pods -A` to see if metric-server runs ok.

From these points you can proceed further.

Comment: Hey @Moulick , No it was not ok and failed with CrashLoopBackOff  error.