# Unable to delete Kubernetes namespace - removing finalizers fails

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-namespace

I've a namespace I'm unable to delete in my Kubernetes cluster. When I run `kubectl get ns traefik -o yaml`, I get the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  annotations:
    cattle.io/status: '{"Conditions":[{"Type":"ResourceQuotaInit","Status":"True","Message":"","LastUpdateTime":"2021-06-11T20:28:59Z"},{"Type":"InitialRolesPopulated","Status":"True","Message":"","LastUpdateTime":"2021-06-11T20:29:00Z"}]}'
    field.cattle.io/projectId: c-5g2hz:p-bl9sf
    lifecycle.cattle.io/create.namespace-auth: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-06-11T20:28:58Z"
  deletionTimestamp: "2021-07-04T07:21:20Z"
  labels:
    field.cattle.io/projectId: p-bl9sf
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:field.cattle.io/projectId: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:field.cattle.io/projectId: {}
      f:status:
        f:phase: {}
    manager: agent
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-06-11T20:28:58Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:cattle.io/status: {}
          f:lifecycle.cattle.io/create.namespace-auth: {}
    manager: rancher
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-06-11T20:28:58Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:conditions:
          .: {}
          k:{"type":"NamespaceContentRemaining"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"NamespaceDeletionContentFailure"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"NamespaceDeletionDiscoveryFailure"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"NamespaceDeletionGroupVersionParsingFailure"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"NamespaceFinalizersRemaining"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-07-04T07:21:26Z"
  name: traefik
  resourceVersion: "15400692"
  uid: 4b198956-bbd5-4bdb-9dc6-9d53feda91e4
spec:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-07-04T07:21:25Z"
    message: 'Discovery failed for some groups, 1 failing: unable to retrieve the
      complete list of server APIs: metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently
      unable to handle the request'
    reason: DiscoveryFailed
    status: "True"
    type: NamespaceDeletionDiscoveryFailure
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-07-04T07:21:26Z"
    message: All legacy kube types successfully parsed
    reason: ParsedGroupVersions
    status: "False"
    type: NamespaceDeletionGroupVersionParsingFailure
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-07-04T07:21:26Z"
    message: All content successfully deleted, may be waiting on finalization
    reason: ContentDeleted
    status: "False"
    type: NamespaceDeletionContentFailure
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-07-04T07:21:26Z"
    message: All content successfully removed
    reason: ContentRemoved
    status: "False"
    type: NamespaceContentRemaining
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-07-04T07:21:26Z"
    message: All content-preserving finalizers finished
    reason: ContentHasNoFinalizers
    status: "False"
    type: NamespaceFinalizersRemaining
  phase: Terminating
```

And when I run `kubectl delete ns traefik --v=10`, the last output is the following:

```
I0708 18:38:26.538676   31537 round_trippers.go:425] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.20.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/faecb19" 'http://127.0.0.1:44427/6614317c-41da-462b-8be3-c6cda2f0df24/api/v1/namespaces?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dtraefik&resourceVersion=17101173&watch=true'
I0708 18:38:27.013394   31537 round_trippers.go:445] GET http://127.0.0.1:44427/6614317c-41da-462b-8be3-c6cda2f0df24/api/v1/namespaces?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dtraefik&resourceVersion=17101173&watch=true 200 OK in 474 milliseconds
I0708 18:38:27.013421   31537 round_trippers.go:451] Response Headers:
I0708 18:38:27.013427   31537 round_trippers.go:454]     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
I0708 18:38:27.013450   31537 round_trippers.go:454]     Date: Thu, 08 Jul 2021 16:38:27 GMT
I0708 18:38:27.013453   31537 round_trippers.go:454]     Connection: keep-alive
I0708 18:38:27.013468   31537 request.go:708] Unexpected content type from the server: "": mime: no media type
```

I already tried to remove the finalizers as described on https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-private/3.2.0?topic=console-namespace-is-stuck-in-terminating-state but after some seconds I finally get `EOF`:

```sh
> curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data-binary @tmp.json http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/traefik/finalize
EOF
```

Is anyone having any idea how I can delete the traefik namespace?

Comment: Can you check, if something else is inside the namespace? `for RES in $(kubectl api-resources --namespaced=true -o name); do echo $RES; kubectl get $RES -o name; done`

Comment: I guess it's about `Discovery failed for some groups, 1 failing: unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs: metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request`. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62464015/15537201)

Comment: @Manuel It shouldn't be the case, because you can delete namespace even if there are resources inside - they will be gone with the namespace - [source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces/#deleting-a-namespace)

Comment: Also `after some seconds I finally get EOF:` - check your json in validator just in case.

Comment: I know, that deleting the namespace should delete all other resources inside. I'm just mentioning it, because i had once an issue, that another resource was not able to get deleted. So the namespace deletion stucked as well.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all these ideas. I fixed the issue for my Metrics server (the problem you posted @moonkotte) and finally, the namespace were delete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki out of comments, feel free to edit and expand.

After analysing a state of the problematic namespace, this part was the main cause of the issue:

```
message: 'Discovery failed for some groups, 1 failing: unable to retrieve the
  complete list of server APIs: metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently
  unable to handle the request'
```

The issue was with `metric server` in kubernetes. Once the `metric server` is available, namespace can be unblocked to be deleted.

Similar issue was resolved in [another answer on the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442679/could-not-get-apiversions-from-kubernetes-unable-to-retrieve-the-complete-list/62464015#62464015).