# How to remove stuck statefullset.apps in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, jitsi, kustomize

I have stuck resources after delete a jitsi stack in my master node. The only pending resources are this two `statefullset.appsset`, no pods are running.

[image: My issue]

If I execute the command:

```
kubectl delete statefulsets shard-0-jvb -n jitsi --force --grace-period=0 --cascade=orphan
```

The console freezes for hours and resources are not removed.

Any other way to force the destroying process?

The stack was created with Kustomize.

[image]

Comment: Check for finalizers in the object, those can't be skipped even with force and friends but you can `kubectl edit` to get rid of them. But of course if there is a stuck finalizer that usually means some other component isn't running which was going to do some kind of cleanup step that you'll be skipping so caveat emptor.

Comment: Try to delete the statefull set yaml, kubectl delete -f <statefullset.yaml>

Comment: I have a lot of files in my directory because is a deploy with kustomize, the execution of kubectl delete -f - it also stays in the console without doing anything

Comment: @MiguelConde have you tried what coderanger suggested? You can describe your stateful set and you will find `finalizer`. Also please refer to [Delete a StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/delete-stateful-set/) and [Force Delete StatefulSet Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/)

Answer (score 1):

Posting the answer as community wiki, feel free to edit and expand.

---

**Stuck objects in general**

Sometimes objects can't be deleted due to `finalizer`(s), you will need to find them by viewing at the whole object e.g. `kubectl get pod pod-name -o json`.

Then there are two options:

1. fix what prevents dependent object to be deleted (for instance it was metrics server - see [another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68319002/15537201))
2. if it's not possible to fix, then `finalizer` should be removed manually by `kubectl edit resource_type resouce_name`

**Stuck statefulsets**

Kubernetes documentation has two parts related to deleting statefulsets (it's a bit more complicated since usually they have persistent volumes as well).

Useful links:

- [Delete a StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/delete-stateful-set/)
- [Force Delete StatefulSet Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/)